# JavaScript function working in IE but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, internet-explorer, firefox

We have a JavaScript/AJAX call in one of our main `.js` files, which works fine in IE 9 but craps out in Firefox 24.6. The function is supposed to load various folders from a specified area and display them on the page. Here is what the code looks like:

```
   folders.load({
            url: url,
            callback: function(records, operation, success) {   
 LINE 732   -->     if (records.length == 0) {
                        store.tree.root.set("text", "No Documents Available");               
                    }
                    for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                        buildNode(records[i]);
                    }
                    buildDocumentGrid();
                    store.sort();
                    treePanel.openDirectory(new queryString().get("directory", null));
            }
          });
```

The page loads perfectly fine in IE. But when we try it in Firefox we get this error to the console:

```
TypeError: records is null
http://www.example.com/public/site/js/committee-docs.js
Line 732
```

There is no reason for `records` to be null but when a break point is added, it is in fact null. Using the exact same url in IE gives us success. Is there some kind of rule that IE chooses to ignore completely but causes Firefox problems? The error does not appear in IEs console, only Firefox.

My question is why does this error occur in IE and not in FF? It is the same code and the `if (records.length == 0) {` is meant to handle empty results. Here is the error output to the console:

```
TypeError: records is null     committee-docs.js (line 732)
"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://www.example.com/public/data/load/rt_zonal.jsp"
rt_zonal.jsp

"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://www.example.com/public/data/lbmp/rt_zonal.jsp"
rt_zonal.jsp

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.example.com/_vti_bin/MetaDataDoc/MetaDoc.svc/getfolders/?folder=%2Fsecure%2Fwebdocs%2Fmarkets_operations%2Fcommittees%2Foc%2Fmeeting_materials&_dc=1408707654820&page=1&start=0&limit=25"
?folde...imit=25

TypeError: records is null
if (records.length == 0) {
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://server:10190/crossdomain.xml"
```

Comment: open up Firebug or your in-browser debugger, and put a breakpoint on that line. what's the value of the `records` variable in the `watch` tab of the debugger?

Comment: if `records === null` then, according to the code you posted, it would fail on this line: `for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {`

Comment: Or you can do a console.log(records) on Firefox with Firebug and tell us what do you get.

Comment: records is in fact null but why would it work in IE?

Comment: what's the value of it on the `for` loop line?

Comment: It breaks before it can get to the for loop

Comment: that doesn't make any sense. the `for` loop is BEFORE the line you say it dies on.

Comment: Wrap all that in a simple `if (records) { ... }` so you actually have a value.

Comment: My apologies i messed up the example code, I'll fix it immediately.

Comment: The issue is probably not in the code you gave us, but on whatever generates the `folders`. If it is a known plugin search on google to see if it is a known bug.

Comment: or maybe the request is failing in FF?

Comment: Yes...it is failing in Firefox...but this is the error it is giving me

Comment: You need to decide if your function should handle cases where there are no results. In that case, wrap the respective parts in an `if (records !== null) { ... }` statement, handle the `else` case, and you should be fine.

Comment: Ok I've done that and it doesn't fix the problem, but why does the same exact code work in IE and not give me a null pointer? that is my question

Comment: Maybe you have a cookie set in IE that is letting you access the data, but fails in FF. Is the request returning an error HTTP status?

Comment: You've passed `records` as an argument. We need the code where you're calling this function, and where the passed argument is defined.

Comment: A common problem like this is that IE doesn't care about content type in the response.  You might be requesting JSON but the server is actually returning HTML and Firefox will ignore HTML results and return null.  Do a `curl --head` on your web service to check.